# Which is more secure for audio streams: RTMP or HTTP Streaming?

Tags: audio, streaming, rtmp

I'd like the .mp3 files being streamed inaccessible to the listeners, but without having to sacrifice mobile compatibility. Which protocol would be best for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `inaccessible streaming`. How are you going to stream if it is inaccessible? :) If a user can listen to any song via streaming, it is **accessible** to user.

If you are trying to prevent users from recording or downloading .mp3 files for your stream, you are falsely thinking [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). If a device can get a data over a network and play it, there is surely a way record the data. It's either by capturing the network traffic, or reverse-engineering your application to understand the protocol you are using to play songs. Whatever you do to obscure your protocol, it will surely be reverse engineered.